# Don't inherit line-height in nested elements

Tags: css

Anyway to make the span with `font-size: 12px` doesn't inherit the line-height of `span` with `font-size:18px`? I want line-height value of 1.5 for 18px and 1.5 value for 12px. I can not separate both `span`

http://jsfiddle.net/WPzVs/6/

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Opera:

```
.example {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.example, .example * {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

---

For Firefox or IE, adding the following rule will make the line-height different for each element but will break the text flow:

```
.example * {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
<p>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
</p>
```

Instead of this:

```
<p>
     <span>
        <span></span>
     </span>
</p>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/WPzVs/8/

Comment: I can't do that, the markup has to be exactly like I've added

Comment: @davidmatas When you say "has to be exactly" do you mean you can't even use some JS to add a new span as a container for the first half of the text, before displaying?

Comment: No, I can't because the markup that I will have, is a little imprevisible. It is the result of the users edits in TinyMCE wysiwig.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible. Although the line height in the inner div is smaller than in the outer one, it's still the outer one that decides the height.

[image: (nested span)]

And even if the smaller text runs over several lines, it's still inside the span with the larger line height, on each of those lines.

Good question though; I've upvoted.